# 'module' object has no attribute '_version_'

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

I'm screwing around with python and its pandas library but I keep running into a problem.  While copying through a tutorial, I try to get the version number for a couple libraries, but when I do so, I get the following: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_version_'`.

Everything else works just fine, but it really doesn't like `'_version_'` for some reason.  Anything I might be leaving out?

See below for the exact code.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data
from pandas import *
pd._version_
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_version_'
```

Comment: official but more verbose method is `pd.version.version` or `pd.version.short_version`

Comment: I noticed that this question has been marked off-topic; I assume the implication is that it's "a simple typographical error."  While I'll certainly defer to the judgement of the admins, I'd like to suggest that this is a legit syntax error. The attribute I intended to enter was indeed false,due to an ignorance of python's syntax.  I can recall previously where I ran into this exact problem in another language and was helped by someone else's forum post; I would therefore suggest that this question should be left standing as the problem will likely be encountered again by another noob like me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use double underscores..

```
In [10]: pandas.__version__
Out[10]: '0.13.1'
```

Which is just a shorthand for `pandas.version.version`

[`PEP8`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#version-bookkeeping) suggests using `__version__` as the global variable to store a version number. Most libraries follow this and then offer a more readable variable or possibly a function which outputs the version in a usable form (like Django for example).